# Add jQuery to WordPress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I need to add jQuery library to WordPress page. The page is rendered by a plugin shortcode.

I've used the below methods but I don't see it working for my jQuery script.

I tried to add these below script in main plugin file where the plugin name and version go.

DESN'T WORK:

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

DESN'T WORK

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.4.2'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

I actually need to add below library to my WordPress front end page?

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
```

but if i use it directly like below then it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Second, How can see it loaded in my browser loaded along with other code?

Comment: add `'alert('test');` to your jquery file and refresh the page, if the script is loaded you'll see the alert message, that's one way. Another way is opening developer console in your browser by clicking F12, go to resources tab and see if the script is loaded.

Comment: jQuery is already included with WordPress...There's usually no reason to load it externally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add script in `wp-admin` then use `admin_head` 
OR 
if you want to add this script on front-end then use `wp_head` in place of `admin_head`

Un-register all jQuery scripts and then call your function to add your custom script.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}

    function add_custom_script() {
        if (!is_admin()) {
              wp_enqueue_script('Jquery_host', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" , array('jquery'));
         }
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'add_custom_script');
```

Comment: I used function add_custom_script() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
          wp_enqueue_script('Jquery_host', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" , array('jquery'));
     }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_script');   but still not working???

Comment: but if i use it directly then it works. <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: you are creating plugin or customizing plugin ? OR you just want to use this script ?

Comment: I have an existing plugin and I'm asked to remove the direct adding of jqeury using script and add it via wordpress technique

Comment: @IrfanDayan i had edited my answer? is your problem resolved ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76609/discussion-between-irfan-dayan-and-noman).

Comment: No. it didn't solve the problem. Still not adding the jquery to WordPress page.

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983563/add-wordpress-jquery-to-cutom-page-template